# Design patterns, are there any recommended patterns for juniors to try to apply, and why?

Tags: design-patterns

I noticed the last few weeks that programmers with higher experience do not discuss "coding" issues very often, rather they discuss design issues. I really love to learn about these patterns, I know the concepts of OO Programming and Design, I'm already applying a decent amount of these principles in my daily work, I try to keep my components modular, reusable, and each one has a specific, well defined responsibilities. Lately i'v been advised to start learning about the various design patterns (the advisor recommended [code complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) as a start), he mentioned some names of some popular patterns (like MVC, SingleTon, and others). So SO Gurus! how should I start learning about these patterns?

**Edit:**  
Because of the detailed explanation i think i'm goona give Saua the point

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. learn about them (I personally like the [C2 Wiki](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DesignPatterns), others might suggest ["Design Patterns"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) by the Gang of Four)
2. apply them
3. grossly mis-apply them (prime candidate: singelton)
4. learn why number 3 was a mistake
5. learn to apply them properly

That's more of a observation report than an instructional list ;-)

Comment: well put! when you learn your tools, lock them in your toolbox and only pull them out when needed! don't become a member of the "pattern of the week" club!

Answer (score 6):

"[Head-First Design Patterns](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000380.html)" may be a fun way to start (also check the discussion on the link).

Comment: This should be required reading for anyone who wants to use design patterns (or wants to write a book on programming, for that matter!)

Answer (score 2):

You start by reading the book Design patterns

[image]
<sub>(source: [codinghorror.com](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/images/design-patterns-book-cover.png))</sub>

Then you start a little project, try them. There is no better way to learn than to try it. Add a few friends for better results.

Answer (score 1):

Though Code Complete is an excellent book (it is absolutely a must-have in my opinion), it is not the best of books to learn about patterns.

If you want to learn about patterns, a good book would be the [Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) book by the Gang of Four. It is a reference to some of the commonly used design patterns.

As for the patterns you mention: I see the MVC pattern more as an architectural pattern then a design pattern, since it effects the structure of the entire system (the architecture) rather than a more isolated piece of code. Singleton (not singletone) is an easy to grasp pattern, though it is overused and the downsides of it are often overlooked, so I wouldn't recommend to start with it (or at least, read it, learn the idea behind it, but don't just start applying it everywhere for the sake of using it - you usually don't *really* need it).

It's hard to recommend a pattern to start with, but I think Factory Method, Command, and Strategy are not too hard to learn, but I'm sure others could disagree.

Answer (score 0):

Start with Gang of Four: [http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Object-Oriented-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0201633612/ref=pd_bbs_sr_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1238418597&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612). A bit outdated but..

Answer (score 0):

Other than the books mentioned here, check [this](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx) site for some theory with good examples.